# Python function redefines variables that are not passed

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I made a function that operates on a numpy array of latitude/longitude values.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import pandas as pd, numpy as np


def regrid2(lats, lons, lat_res=0.25, lon_res=0.25):

    # round lat/lon values to nearest decimal degree according to specified
    # resolution and reshape the array
    lats[lats<=0] = lat_res*(np.round(lats[lats<=0]/lat_res)) - lat_res/2
    lats[lats>0]  = lat_res*(np.round(lats[lats>0]/lat_res))  + lat_res/2

    lons[lons<=0] = lon_res*(np.round(lons[lons<=0]/lon_res)) + lon_res/2
    lons[lons>0]  = lon_res*(np.round(lons[lons>0]/lon_res))  - lon_res/2

    lats = np.reshape(lats, (lats.size,1),  order='F')
    lons = np.reshape(lons, (lons.size,1),  order='F')

    lats = 0

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df


lat = np.arange(80.111, 90, 5)
lon = np.arange(170.11, 180,0.33)

df = regrid2(lat,lon)
```

When I call regrid2 my lat/lon arrays change, even though the function is not returning new arrays for lat/lon.

E.g., before calling regrid:

```
>>> lat.min()
    80.111000000000004
>>> lon.min()
    170.11000000000001
```

AFTER calling regrid:

```
>>> lat.min()
    80.125
>>> lon.min()
    169.875
```

I do not recall having similar problems before.  What makes this particularly strange is that I ran the same script last night without problems, but this morning the function is redefining my lat/lon variables.  I have re-started my IDE, but I have not been able to determine why this is happening.

That being said, if I copy lat/lon into regrid then I have no problems.  e.g.

```
df = regrid2(lat.copy(),lon.copy())
>>> lat.min()
    80.111000000000004
>>> lon.min()
    170.11000000000001
```

I would like to identify the sudden change in behavior.  I typically work in Pandas these days, not so much with numpy, so maybe there has been no change in behavior, rather I am just noticing this.

Python 2.7, Numpy 1.10.4

Comment: your code looks incorrect `df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df` is the same as your working code?

Comment: You are passing a mutable value to a function and then mutating it. Numpy arrays have always been mutable in this fashion.

Comment: Your title is misleading, the variables `lat` and `lon` are definitely passed.

Comment: Using different names for a function's arguments doesn't stop variables from being passed..

Comment: @ IanS  You are correct.  I meant the variables are not passed out of the function.  I should have used returned instead.  Sorry.

Comment: @ EdChum, no, my working code creates a dataframe based on the lat/lon pairs and data that is passed into regrid2.  I just cleaned everything up to make the MWE that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing mutable data to the function, then mutating it.

You could use

```
def regrid2(lats, lons, lat_res=0.25, lon_res=0.25):
    lats, lons = np.copy(lats), np.copy(lons)
```

to work with copies instead?

Comment: That is what I suspected.  Thanks for clarifying.  I always thought of functions automatically making copies and never actually touching the referenced variables.    Though this may be normal, I have to admit that this still sounds like unusual behavior.